# #NAME? error after renaming all my 'ThisWorksheet' modules

Tags: excel, vba, macos, rename

I have a excel workbook with many worksheets and a lot of data. One of my VBA functions is the following. It has been working perfectly well.

```
Function TextResult(Name As String) As String
  Select Case Name
    Case Is = "Text1"
      Name = "Result1"
    Case Is = "Text2"
      Name = "Result2"
    Case Is = "Text3"
      Name = "Result"
  End Select
End Function
```

Then I added a Sub that renames my modules:

```
Sub Whats_In_A_Name()
    ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("Module1").name = "TextResult"
    ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("Module2").name = "Name2"
End Sub
```

This one gave an error but renamed them all, including itself.

But now I get a #NAME? error on all the cells that use these modules that are made like the one above, so all Case functions. And I have no clue how to correct this. Anyone an idea?

Comment: Use a different name for your UDF than the exact name of the module that holds it.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks a million! It also explains why the other modules did work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As above:

Use a different name for your UDF other than the exact name of the module that holds the function.